# Suppressing the error from IP route command

Tags: bash

I have a shell script which gets me the IPv4 address. Here is the command which I am using:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}'
```

I try to run the same command in pure IPv6 environment and gets the following error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
```

Is there a way to suppress this error? I mean to say I don't want any such error to be printed in my console logs.

I have tried doing:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}' 2> /dev/null
```

but I could still see the error.

Comment: try redirecting error first.. `ip route get 8.8.8.8 2> /dev/null | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}' 2> /dev/null
```

The problem with this is that the `2>` applies to the `awk` command which, of course, is not printing any error to it's `stderr`. You want to suppress errors from `ip` instead. So, you have the redirect `ip`'s `stderr`.

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 2> /dev/null | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}'
```